# How to access texinfo documentation from emacs?

Tags: emacs, manual, texinfo

How does one access Texinfo manuals (commandline example would be: info gdb) from within emacs? This does not appear to be M-x info as I don’t see gdb in the menus)

Is there a list, perhaps, which has paths to info manuals that I need to check to make sure emacs has the same locations to look for these manuals as the info command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've installed the info docs, eg. `gdb-doc` package or whatever, you should be able to see the info page with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `info-display-manual` `gdb`.

As far as the lookup path, you could check `Info-directory-list` from emacs to see if it is getting initialized properly from your `INFOPATH`.